# Delete specific string from Local Storage array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, local-storage

I have this code

```
function deleteElement() {
        const myArray = map(listItems, getText);
        var elementToDelete =document.getElementById('deleteElement').value;
        const index = myArray.findIndex((item) => item.includes(elementToDelete));

            if (index > -1) {
            // delete and update local storage
            console.log("found element and index ", index);
            let moment = localStorage.getItem('pelis_guardades');
            let deleted = moment.splice(index, 1);
            localStorage.setItem('pelis_guardades', JSON.stringify(deleted))
            console.log(deleted);
            }
    }
```

I have found the index of the element of the array that I want to delete, everything's good, but now I would like to "update" the local storage to delete the item from the index.

I can delete the specific value on the array that loads into the local Storage. Called myArray.

```
const myArray = map(listItems, getText);
```

myArray contains the "raw string data" that then gets put on the local Storage via,

```
localStorage.setItem('things',JSON.stringify(myArray));
```

How can I delete from the localStorage?

I've tried, the splice method on the local storage but doesn't work!!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try to parsing the moment variable to JSON
using

**edit**

```
function deleteElement() {
    const myArray = map(listItems, getText);
    var elementToDelete =document.getElementById('deleteElement').value;
    const index = myArray.findIndex((item) => item.includes(elementToDelete));

        if (index > -1) {
        // delete and update local storage
        console.log("found element and index ", index);
        let moment = localStorage.getItem('pelis_guardades');
        //try to add this code
        let moment_parse = JSON.parse(moment);
        let deleted = moment_parse.splice(index, 1);//edit
        localStorage.setItem('pelis_guardades', JSON.stringify(deleted))
        console.log(deleted);
        }
```

before you splice the *moment variable*

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you've made a mistake using `Array.splice`. 
This method mutates the given array. 
You don't need the result of the `splice` operation. Instead you must pass the array as the new value to update the localstorage.

```
// 1. read value
const moment = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('pelis_guardades'))

// 2. mutate given array by removing one element from index.
moment.splice(index, 1);

// 3. write value
localStorage.setItem('pelis_guardades', JSON.stringify(moment))
```